# monitor file permission changes

Tags: permissions, filesystems

How can I figure out which process is changing the permissions of a file?

on a Debian server, I have the problem that something is changing the permissions on `/dev/null` every day at 6:20 (since 3 weeks). When I set the correct permissions, they are set back between a few minutes. Then I set it again and after that permissions stay correct until next day 6:20. It doesn't matter at which time I set the permissions.

Comment: This [Link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=66921) talks about a monitoring tool `inotify-tools`, to monitor permission changes. Have a look!

Comment: that's not what i need, because i know when the file is changed. i need to know which Process (PID, Name) is changing the file.

Comment: what was the culprit?

Comment: For me, the culprit was `/root/.nano_history` symlinked to `/dev/null`. So everytime nano was used and wrote its history it attempted to correct the permissions... (I can imagine this happening with other programs in a similar setup)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install `auditd` and run:

```
sudo auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S fchmod -S chmod -S fchmodat \
  -F path=/dev/null -k dev-null-chmod
sudo auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S fchmod -S chmod -S fchmodat \
  -F path=/dev/null -k dev-null-chmod
```

You'd find the culprit in the output of:

```
sudo ausearch -ik dev-null-chmod
```

You'll see the command name, pid and parent pid in there. If the  command name is `chmod`, you'll probably want to know what ran that command. If the ppid is no longer there, you may want to also monitor all the process creation and/or executed commands with the audit system again or with bsd process accounting.